# Passing object from one application to another

Tags: android, android-sdk-2.3

I need to pass a custom object from an activity of one application to the main activity of another.

Will I be able to accomplish this using intent.putExtra as shown:

```
putExtra("key",obj);
```

It was showing error since putExtra method does not support this. How can this be achieved?

Any help is appreciated.

**EDIT**

The following class' instance, I need to pass to another application. I would have the object 'obj' as follows, which I need to pass:

```
CounterAndNotifier obj = new CounterAndNotifier(5, this)
```

obj is the object to be passed

```
public class CounterAndNotifier
{
private int counter = 0;
private int count;
private Runnable runnable;

public CounterAndNotifier(int count, Runnable runnable)
{
    this.count = count;
    this.runnable = runnable;
}

public synchronized void incrementCounter()
{
    counter++;
    if (counter == count) {
        runnable.run();
    }
}
}
```

Comment: Read About Parceable Interface

Comment: putExtra pass String value but why r u pass ? i thing make object public static ane use in other activity..i thing its simple way..

Comment: Chirag Patel - This is about passing between applications activities. Not between the activities of same application

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Update 2: Example constructor:

```
CounterAndNotifier counter = new CounterAndNotifier(0, new SerializableRunnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {

            }
        });
```

or

```
SerializableRunnable runnable = new SerializableRunnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            /* Running code here */
        }
});
CounterAndNotifier counter = new CounterAndNotifier(0, runnable);
```

Update: Runnable is an interface and isn't Serializable by itself.  To get around this, create a new class like this:

```
public abstract class SerializableRunnable implements Runnable, Serializable {
    /* Nothing needs to go here */
}
```

Then change your references of Runnable to SerializableRunnable and you should be able to serialize your object into an intent without a problem.

Your new object would look like this:

```
public class CounterAndNotifier implements Serializable
{
    private int counter = 0;
    private int count;
    private SerializableRunnable runnable;

    public CounterAndNotifier(int count, SerializableRunnable runnable)
    {
        this.count = count;
        this.runnable = runnable;
    }

    public synchronized void incrementCounter()
    {
        counter++;
        if (counter == count) {
            runnable.run();
        }
    }
}
```

You can still create your Runnable objects the same way, just with a different name.

Original Answer:
You can't put a regular object into an `Intent` extra.  If your object members are all serializable types then you can just implement the `Serializable` interface and then you can put the object into the `Intent`.  Otherwise you can implement `Parceable` and flatten your object into a Parcel.

Using `Serializable` requires much less code changes so long as your object members are basic types.  Also, you should check was is supported by the receiving application first to determine which you should use.

It'd look something like this:

```
public class YourObject implements Serializable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = -6242440735315628245L;
    /* Your class members */

}
```

Adding to the intent:

```
Intent intent = new Intent();
intent.putExtra("YourKey", new YourObject());
```

Getting out of the intent:

```
YourObject obj = (YourObject)intent.getSerializableExtra("YourKey");
```

Comment: I've edited my question showing the object I need to pass to another app. I will definitely try this out tomorrow and accept your answer if it works. Hope the objects are serializable and it works the way you suggested.

Comment: Updated my answer to reflect the object you're trying to pass.

Comment: would be great, if you can just show how I should call the constructor CounterAndNotifier from another class. Should this class also implement Runnable/ Serializble? How the SerializableRunnable object be passed to constructor?

Comment: Updated answer with example constructor call.  The calling class doesn't need to be serializable, only the object that's going into the intent should implement serializable.